# No internet connection on Kali Linux VirtualBox after changing MAC adress with macchanger or ifconfig command

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, internet-connection, mac-address

i just started learning Kali Linux as part of Ethical Hacking step by step program.
After installing VirtualBox and Kali on it as VM , one of the steps was learning how to 'spoof' your MAC adress .. they showed commands that i suposed  to use `ifconfig eth0 down , ifconfig eht0 hw ether 00:11:22:33:44:55 , ifconfig eth0 up` i tried that command but my internet connection was lost .. MAC adress was different but no connection , so i looked it up on google and i saw this other macchanger command .. i tired that but its basicly the same thing. I read somewhere that even if i change it .. there is no use of it becouse its my MAC adress on Windows PC that comes first if anyone looked it up . So is there any way to fix connection problem after changing MAC adress .. and should i buy a laptop to install Kali on or is it fine to just use it like a Virtual Machine on my PC ?

Comment: Your VM is using the Network Card of the Host machine. Consider a USB Wireless card, do a USB passthrough to the VM and try MAC spoofing with the USB Wireless.

Comment: I wonder if it's a limitation of VirtualBox, as it's a virtual NIC and the MAC address  is assigned by / configured in the app. It's hard to say how it handle things internally (before reading its open source code). Either way I would do this sort of networking learning with Hyper-V if not a Linux host instead. (Also better learn basic concepts like the different kinds/modes of network for VMs, like which one is what you need and how to configure them in the host, before start using one to learn hacking/pentesting whatsoever).

Comment: Also I wouldn't start with wireless either, as it often poses extra limitations/criteria due to the nature of it. Device passthrough is often problematic as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible when running Kali through a VM.

I have been running into the exact same issue and found that the only way to 'spoof' your virtual machine's MAC address is through the virtualization software itself. There should be an option for this in your 'Network' settings, in the VirtualBox GUI, after enabling the 'Advance' drop down options. From here, you can either manually input a new MAC address or you can simply select the icon to generate a new random MAC address. This essentially achieves the same thing as the -m (--mac) and -r (--random) options respectively, as found in the macchanger utility.

If you needed to do anything further, you could run macchanger on your host system, providing you're running linux, although that may be pointless overkill, otherwise I believe that using the VirtualBox GUI is all you can do here. If you ran a live boot of Kali from a USB, or installed it on bare metal, MAC address 'spoofing' should work natively no problem. However, I think if you are just learning then running it in a virtual environment is fine and protects you from messing up your host operating system too!

Hope that's helpful :)